# Programmatically set ICQ status

Tags: c#, icq

I'd like to edit/set icq status with a c# app when a certain action occurs.
I know there's an API that seems much too oversized for that. Can someone suggest a better way *e.g.* manipulating a registry value or something?

How would you do this?

Comment: It's a very specific question, It'll be hard to find an easy answer. However, ICQ client seems to have very rough edges in it's code. Maybe searching for ICQ on the registry, or checking what the DLLs are for? Maybe it's trivial. Also, checking the API docs may prove helpful.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I really have to say it : is ICQ actually *still* used by anybody ;) ?

Answer (score 0):

You will need to research the ability to connect with a ICQ client inorder to change a status, and/or if it will allow you to do this. Using the API is the easiest way to do it. Also, take a look at building a plugin for Pidgin. That would be able to solve the issue for you.